# Date Formats displayed in ASP.NET Gridview not DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2017

How do I make asp.net gridview display dates in British English (dd/mm/yyyy). They are (dd/mm/yyyy) using the Date Picker but not when displayed in the Grid and saved to SQL Server 2012? Please no sarcasm!
The problem is with SQL Server 2012 as I amusing SMSS but cannot see how to format the fields e.g. Access Db allows masks ( I know that is a naive comparison).

Comment: Dates dont have an intrinsic format, if the column datatype is `Date` they will save correctly.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] with us.

Answer (score -2):

You probably could solve this in c# some neat way. But I usually solve this by using:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),yourDateTimeCol, 103) 
From yourTable
```

I select this from database and just show the string in app. If I need to do some dateTime operations in app i can just do eg. `DateTime.Parse(valFromSqlSever);`